# Find related products in Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have products with an attribute called "siblings", which is a CSV list of related SKUs of another products.

What I need to do is the following: when I search one of these products, the result set must contain the matching product along with all the "siblings".

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

On the admin, go to Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes, Select "Siblings", select "Yes" on "Use on quick search".

We have a similar attribute implemented and it works fine, at least on solr, do test if this works for you on regular fulltext.

Comment: it didn't work. are you sure we are talking about the same? my attribute has the following format: sku1,sku2,sku3. I'd need those products to also appear in the results.

Comment: Yes my attribute works just like that, make sure you update your indexes